# Vincular Evento a exclusao da TAG Classe

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-eventos, eventos-do-mouse

Eu preciso fazer com que ao clicar no botão "REMOVE" a funcao removeChild remova exatamente o produto no qual o botão REMOVE clicado está vinculado.

Atualmente, tudo está certo mas eu sei que neste código o product[0] faz com que apenas o elemento de index 0 do array(HTMLcollection) seja excluido, nao importa qual botão "REMOVE" eu clique. COMO FAÇO para ele excluir somente o produto especifico??? Segue código ....

```
function removeProduct(event) {
  var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

  var product = document.getElementsByClassName('product');


  if (parent.removeChild(product[0])){
    calculateAll();
  }
}
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const calculatePricesBtn = document.getElementById('calculate');
  calculatePricesBtn.addEventListener('click', calculateAll);

  const removeProductsBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-remove');
  for(var i=0; i<removeProductsBtn.length; i++){
  removeProductsBtn[i].addEventListener('click', removeProduct);}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <title>Ironhack Cart</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Ironhack Cart</h1>
    <table id="cart">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Product Name</th>
          <th>Unit Price</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Subtotal</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="product">
          <td class="name">
            <span>Ironhack Rubber Duck</span>
          </td>
          <td class="price">$<span>25.00</span></td>
          <td class="quantity">
            <input type="number" value="0" min="0" placeholder="Quantity" />
          </td>
          <td class="subtotal">$<span>0</span></td>
          <td class="action">
            <button class="btn btn-remove">Remove</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="product">
          <td class="name">
            <span>Ironhack Beach Towel</span>
          </td>
          <td class="price">$<span>12.50</span></td>
          <td class="quantity">
            <input type="number" value="0" min="0" placeholder="Quantity" />
          </td>
          <td class="subtotal">$<span>0</span></td>
          <td class="action">
            <button class="btn btn-remove" id="butaozinho">Remove</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Iteration 2: Add more products here -->
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr class="create-product">
          <td>
            <input id='nomeProduto' type="text"  placeholder="Product Name" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id='precoUnitario' type="number"  min="0" value="0" placeholder="Product Price" />
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <button id="create" class="btn">Create Product</button>
          </td>
        </tr> 
      </tfoot>
    </table>
    <p class="calculate-total">
      <button id="calculate" class="btn btn-success">Calculate Prices</button>
    </p>
    <h2 id="total-value">Total: $<span>0</span></h2>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Utilize `function removeProduct(event) { event.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove(); }`. Este código irá pegar o elemento que foi clicado, capturar o elemento avó (*tr*) e removê-lo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há algumas formas. Quando um elemento sobre a ação de clique, o *JavaScript*, automaticamente, passa um parâmetro do tipo [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget). Com este parâmetro, podemos acessar o elemento clicado e todos os ascendentes dele.

Para isso, basta acessar o evento e utilizar os atributos `.parentElement` até chegar ao elemento que você quer remover.

**Código**

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const removeProductsBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-remove');
  
  for(let i = 0; i<removeProductsBtn.length; i++){
    removeProductsBtn[i].addEventListener('click', removeProduct);
  }
})

function removeProduct(ev) {
  ev                /* Captura o evento */
    .target         /* Acessa o elemento clicado (button) */
    .parentElement  /* Acessa o elemento pai (td.action) */
    .parentElement  /* Acessa o elemento avô (tr.product) */
    .remove()       /* Remove o elemento avô */
}
```

```html
<h1>Ironhack Cart</h1>
<table id="cart">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Subtotal</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="product">
      <td class="name">
        <span>Ironhack Rubber Duck</span>
      </td>
      <td class="price">$<span>25.00</span></td>
      <td class="quantity">
        <input type="number" value="0" min="0" placeholder="Quantity" />
      </td>
      <td class="subtotal">$<span>0</span></td>
      <td class="action">
        <button class="btn btn-remove">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
      <td class="name">
        <span>Ironhack Beach Towel</span>
      </td>
      <td class="price">$<span>12.50</span></td>
      <td class="quantity">
        <input type="number" value="0" min="0" placeholder="Quantity" />
      </td>
      <td class="subtotal">$<span>0</span></td>
      <td class="action">
        <button class="btn btn-remove" id="butaozinho">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Iteration 2: Add more products here -->
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="create-product">
      <td>
        <input id='nomeProduto' type="text" placeholder="Product Name" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id='precoUnitario' type="number" min="0" value="0" placeholder="Product Price" />
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <button id="create" class="btn">Create Product</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<p class="calculate-total">
  <button id="calculate" class="btn btn-success">Calculate Prices</button>
</p>
<h2 id="total-value">Total: $<span>0</span></h2>
```

Uma alternativa, é utilizar atributos *HTML* para identificar os elementos `<tr>` dos produtos, dessa forma podemos buscar o elemento através de sua identificação, exemplo:

```js
function removeProduct(id) {
  document.querySelector(`#product-${id}`)
    .remove()
}
```

```html
<h1>Ironhack Cart</h1>
<table id="cart">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Subtotal</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="product" id="product-1">
      <td class="name">
        <span>Ironhack Rubber Duck</span>
      </td>
      <td class="price">$<span>25.00</span></td>
      <td class="quantity">
        <input type="number" value="0" min="0" placeholder="Quantity" />
      </td>
      <td class="subtotal">$<span>0</span></td>
      <td class="action">
        <button class="btn btn-remove" onclick="removeProduct(1)">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="product" id="product-11">
      <td class="name">
        <span>Ironhack Beach Towel</span>
      </td>
      <td class="price">$<span>12.50</span></td>
      <td class="quantity">
        <input type="number" value="0" min="0" placeholder="Quantity" />
      </td>
      <td class="subtotal">$<span>0</span></td>
      <td class="action">
        <button class="btn btn-remove" onclick="removeProduct(11)">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Iteration 2: Add more products here -->
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="create-product">
      <td>
        <input id='nomeProduto' type="text" placeholder="Product Name" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id='precoUnitario' type="number" min="0" value="0" placeholder="Product Price" />
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <button id="create" class="btn">Create Product</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<p class="calculate-total">
  <button id="calculate" class="btn btn-success">Calculate Prices</button>
</p>
<h2 id="total-value">Total: $<span>0</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso de forma simples usando a função [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/closest). Ela lhe permite encontrar um elemento pai usando *querySelector*, supondo que todas as suas tags `tr` possuam a classe *product*, você poderia usar um código semelhante a este:

```
function removeProduct(event) {
    var product = event.target.closest('.product');
    if (product) {
        product.remove();
        calculateAll();
    }
}
```